# How to set time to output numbers by difference 1 second

Tags: c++, random, output, sleep, srand

I have a program like this:

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand(time());
    int izlases_sk, a, b, c, d, e;
    cout << "Enter 5 numbers" << endl;
    cin >> a;
    cin >> b;
    cin >> c;
    cin >> d;
    cin >> e;
    cout << endl;

    for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++)
    {
        izlases_sk = rand() % 77;
        cout << izlases_sk << "\t";
        if( izlases_sk == a || izlases_sk == b || izlases_sk == c || izlases_sk == d || izlases_sk == e)
            cout << " You predicted this number!\t";
        else
            cout << "No\t";
        {
            if (a > 77 || b > 77 || c > 77 || d > 77 || e > 77)
                goto end;
        }
        if ((x + 1) % 5 == 0)
            cout<<endl;
    }
    end:
    getch ();
}
```

I want that my randomly generated numbers get outputted one by one with 1 second delay in between.
How can I do it?

**Example:** c++ generate `76`, then after one second he generates next number.

Comment: Generates one number then next number after 1 second and so on.

Comment: Just a general tip. Don't use goto clauses. Just return exit_succes or simply 0.

Comment: replace srand with this one srand((unsigned) time (0));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Sleep` function (The [Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and the [Linux](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sleep) version)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a C++11 compliant compiler then simply insert the following line wherever you want the program to *sleep* for a second (you need headers `<thread>` and `<chrono>`):

```
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
```

Also this code is portable.